# Why doesn't "$^J" match a new line character after another line?

Tags: regular-expressions

I want to match two or more consecutive lines with numbers only, e.g.:

```
abc
1
2
abc
```

In Emacs, my regex is `\(^ *[[:digit:]]+ *$^J\)\{2,\}`, but it doesn't match any. I find `\(^ *[[:digit:]]+ *^J\)\{2,\}` can match.

Isn't it true that `$` doesn't consume a character, but signals the end of a line (just before a newline character)?

In Python, I remember it doesn't matter that I specify `$\n` or `\n`. So why does it matter in Emacs? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

> Isn't it true that $ doesn't consume a character, but signals the end of a line (just before a newline character)?

$ can only be used at the end of a regexp, or just before `\)` or `\|`.

[From the manual:](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexps.html)

> $
>
> is similar to ‘^’ but matches only at the end of a line. Thus, ‘x+$’ matches a string of one ‘x’ or more at the end of a line.
>     For historical compatibility reasons, ‘$’ can be used with this meaning only at the end of the regular expression, or before ‘)’
>   or ‘\|’.

What these "historical reasons" are, I don't know.

So if you want to use `$` and `^J` you can replace `$^J` with `\($\)^J` and it will work as expected, though there is no need to express the end of a line in this redundant way.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the `$` is redundant when used just before a `^J` character (aka LF or newline or `\n`).  So while @JordonBiondo has the right answer, I think a better alternative is to just ditch the `$`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `\n` to represent the newline should work (compare [this description of Emacs newline representation](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_line_ending_char.html).  This re puts point just after the 2:

```
(re-search-forward "\\(^\\s-*[0-9]+\\s-*\n\\)\\{2,\\}" nil t)

abc
1
2
abc
```

Comment: This only works when the regexp is defined in an elisp string, when you are enterring a regexp interactively, you must insert a literal newline. Since OP's regexps are not double quoted I assume this is what they are doing.